# Timestamp to date in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to convert a string field called timestamp with value 1510722000000 in date format field in Logstash. My sole purpose is to visualize data in kibana using this date field. I tried using the date filter but it does not create the target field for me. Can anyone tell me How can I achieve this

My date filter looks like this

```
date {
    timezone => "UTC"
    match => ["timestamp", "UNIX_MS"]
    target => "@timestamp1"
}
```

Comment: `it does not create the target field for me`: the log stored in logstash does not have the field `@timestamp1`, is that what you mean? If so, do they have the tag `_dateparsefailure`? If they have this tag, it means that the filter failed to parse the field `timestamp`. Other than that, I see no problem in what you've posted.

Comment: @baudsp I did not get any parsing errors. All the data is ingested properly in elasticsearch with the data type I want. But the date filter does not create a field called timestamp1  which I can use.

Comment: `does not create a field called timestamp1 which I can use.` The field is not created? Or the field is not usable? If first, the problem would be when injecting the data in elasticsearch (perhaps a template problem). If second, the problem either is elasticsearch (perhaps the field is not a date in the mapping) or in kibana (have you tried [reloading the field list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.2/index-patterns.html#reload-fields)?)

Comment: @baudsp it is a template problem I guess the field is not being created.

Comment: @baudsp it is a dateparser failure

Comment: "tags" => [
    [0] "multiline",
    [1] "_dateparsefailure"
],
      "path" => "C:\\Users\\186181152\\Downloads\\xml_dev\\27.xml",
"@timestamp" => 2018-02-16T16:08:33.969Z,

Comment: What does the `timestamp` field look like? Maybe the wrong value is extracted from your xml doc. Or perhaps it is extracted with traling linebreak/withespace.

Comment: My Sample input
< measurement timestamp="1510722000000" blah blah>

Comment: Also, They did not have trailing whitespace

Comment: Hi also I noticed that the timestamp value of 1510722000000 when converted to human readable time is not correctly parsed 11/16/49842 @ 8:00am (UTC)

Comment: Hi, it seems the problem with my input if I remove the last 3 digit of my input that the online epoch converter parses the time correctly. Will try that and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date filter used by me is correct. The problem is my input from timestamp is an array of milliseconds from epoch time. Date filter cannot convert an array of values in date field. To parse the values in array we can use Ruby filter.

Take a look on this post [Parsing array of epoch time values in Ruby filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934845/converting-epoch-time-to-date-in-logstash-using-ruby-filter/48975232#48975232)

please note it will still not convert into datefield format but just parse the values.