# Converting epoch time to date in logstash using ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a field name "timestamp" in my configuration. It holds an array of data in epoch time (miliseconds). I want to use Ruby filter to convert each epoch time in the array and convert into Date format consumable by Kibana. I am trying to convert each date field and store in a new field as an array. I am getting syntax errors. Can anyone help me out ? I am new to Ruby.

```
ruby {
code => {'
event.get("timestamp").each do |x| {    
event["timestamp1"] = Time.at(x)
    } 
'}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//This will take an timestamp array with values in milliseconds from epoch  time and create a new field with parsed time. This code is part of ruby filter  Note : This does not convert into Date field format

```
code => '
    timestamps = Array.new
    event.get("timestamp").each_with_index { |x, i| 
    timestamps.push(Time.at(x.to_i / 1000)) }
    event.set( "timestamp1" , timestamps)
  '
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about logstash, but the Ruby code you include within quotes is invalid. Try this:

```
ruby {
  code => {'
    event.get("timestamp").each { |x| event["timestamp1"] = Time.at(x) } 
'}
}
```

If you intend your timestamp key to increment, then you need to include an index:

```
ruby {
  code => {'
    event.get("timestamp").each_with_index { |x, i| event["timestamp#{i}"] = Time.at(x) } 
'}
}
```

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks

Comment: it does not go well with Logstash